# Using PhantomJs, how to get and handle the new page?

Tags: phantomjs

Source Code:

```
page.open(url, function(status) {

    page.evaluate(function() {

         //jump to a new page, I want to get and handle this page 
        $('.imgItem .maskWraper').eq(0).click();


    });

    console.log(status);

    phantom.exit();
});
```

I use PhantomJs to load a page, then I get the botton and click, this button jump to a new page, how to get this new page? And how to continue to interact on new page like:

```
newPage.evaluate(function() {
    button.click();
});
```

Comment: There is no `newPage`, because the new page is loaded in the same `page` instance.

Comment: Thanks for  Artjom B,  and thank you for your answer to the kind of PhantomsJs questions. With the help of people like you, my project finished! :)